# How can I use OnKeyUp to trigger a javascript over and over?

Tags: javascript, forms, triggers, field, onkeyup

First time asking a question here so please be gentle... I use a set of perl script (no judging please) that are great for simple flat file database creation, updating and searching (www.ezscripting.com/csv). I have used these scripts well beyond the intended uses including being able to display data using a javascript to call the data.

What I'd like to do is have a form field that searches a specific field in the database, let's say . What I'd like to do is allow a visitor to start to type in the search field and have the OnKeyUp event handler trigger a javascript call that will pull up to 5 entries in my database.

Is there a way to have OnKeyUp in an input field tag trigger an embedded javascript each time a new letter is typed?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp)
that uses AJAX to do what I think you're trying to do.